# Full-text search not installing while in silent install string

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, silent-installer

I have '/FEATURES=SQLENGINE,FULLTEXT' in my silent install string for SQL Server Express 2019.
Though Fulltext search is not installing.

I have included this silent install within an installer, it also creates a named instance.
Later in the installer i run some query's to fill the database and create all tables. Full-text search is needed for this.

I get the error: 'full-text search is not installed or a full-text component cannot be loaded'

Does anyone have some clearance as to why this may be happening?

Comment: Are you installing Express with Advanced Services?

Comment: Yes! thank you! I completely looked over this. I'm quite new to all this...